# Set layout_margin using databinding

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

I use data building in my application and I'm new to this.
I can't change the layout_marginLeft code.
I have seen many examples but they do not work for me.
Here is my code in the model.

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_marginLeft")
public static void setLayoutMarginLeft(View view, float marginLeft) {
    if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        p.setMargins((int) marginLeft, p.topMargin, p.rightMargin, p.bottomMargin);
        view.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

xml file

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.aofled.test.window.activity.sleep.SleepActivityViewModel" />
</data>

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sleep"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tap to screen....."
            android:textColor="@color/selector_inactive"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@{viewModel.layout_marginLeft}"
            />
```

I cannot build the project. I wrote:

```
****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find accessor com.aofled.test.window.activity.sleep.SleepActivityViewModel.layout_marginLeft file:C:\!work\kohote_ch_android 4\kohotehc_android\client\src\main\res\layout\activity_sleep.xml loc:26:45 - 26:71 ****\ data binding error ****
```

What should I change to make it work?

Comment: How are you defining the `layout_marginLeft` property in `SleepActivityViewModel`? Apparently the error is suggesting it cannot find the getter for `layout_marginLeft ` in your viewmodel.

Comment: I define this property in this way. It is located in SleepActivityViewModel. 
This is the same code that is at the top of my question. @BindingAdapter("android:layout_marginLeft")
public static void setLayoutMarginLeft(View view, float marginLeft) {
    if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        p.setMargins((int) marginLeft, p.topMargin, p.rightMargin, p.bottomMargin);
        view.requestLayout();
    }
}

Comment: What does the getter for `@{viewModel.layout_marginLeft}` look like in `SleepActivityViewModel`?

Comment: There are two parts to the statement. `android:layout_marginLeft` and `@{viewModel.layout_marginLeft}`. You have provided the binding adapter for `android:layout_marginLeft`. The code is there in the question. The second part `@{viewModel.layout_marginLeft}` is fetching the property `layout_marginLeft` from `SleepActivityViewModel`. This property must have some getter. The compiler is complaining about the missing or misdefined getter.

Comment: At the moment, only what I added at the top. Should I add something else to my code?

Comment: Full definition of class `SleepActivityViewModel` please.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found a solution for my problem.
I hope someone will help.

My .xml

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.kohote.homecare.window.activity.sleep.SleepActivityViewModel" />
</data>

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sleep"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sleep_mode_text"
            android:textColor="@color/selector_inactive"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            app:layout_marginLeft="@{viewModel.marginLeft}"
            />
```

My SleepActivityViewModel

```
public ObservableField<Float> marginLeft = new ObservableField<>();


@BindingAdapter({"bind:layout_marginLeft"})
public static void setLayoutMarginLeft(TextView view, float marginLeft) {
    if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        p.setMargins((int) marginLeft, p.topMargin, p.rightMargin, p.bottomMargin);
        view.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

and my Setter

```
marginLeft.set(100f, 900f);
```

This is a working version.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This worked very well for me too.